# I want to delay the dropdown hide and animation for the same time

Tags: jquery

Here is the code, when hovering on the `li` items the tabs animate and grow to `270px` simultaneously opening a dropdown `div` of same width containing input fields, but when I move the mouse out of the `dropdown` div or try to select something from option lists the dropdown closes,I want some delay or other solution for this issue

```
$(function() {
            /**
             * the menu
             */
            var $menu = $('#ldd_menu');

            /**
             * for each list element,
             * we show the submenu when hovering and
             * expand the span element (title) to 270px
             */
            $menu.children('li').each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var $span = $this.children('span');
                $span.data('width',$span.width());

                $this.bind('mouseenter',function(){
                    $menu.find('.ldd_submenu').stop(true,true).hide();
                    $span.stop().animate({'width':'270px'},300,function(){
                        $this.find('.ldd_submenu').slideDown(300);
                    });
                }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                    $this.find('.ldd_submenu').stop(true,true).hide();

                    $span.stop().animate({'width':$span.data('width')+'px'},300);
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure in jQuery, but in straight javascript clicking on the item gives it focus and the focus is retained until you click elsewhere, so what you want to do is test for loss of focus (I'm guessing mouseenter/mouseleave check if the mouse is hovering over the item).

Timers aren't really the way to go about this because different people may ponder the options on the menu for longer than others and you want to give them the freedom to do that.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `delay()`:

```
....bind('mouseleave',function(){
         $this.find('.ldd_submenu').delay(300).stop(true,true).hide();
         $span.delay(300).stop().animate({'width':$span.data('width')+'px'},300);
       });
```